# MySQL Problem writing query

Tags: mysql

I currently have a table which holds catalog information with the following fields:

catalog, price, product_id, size, pack_size, stock_level

A product can appear in the catalog up to 30 times (the same product with a different size and/or in a different pack size must have a unique catalog_id)

I now want to display a table which has sizes down the left, pack sizes across the top and prices as the data, but don't know how to write the query.

Comment: could you show an example of the resultset you need?

Comment: You want a "PIVOT". Search for that in combination with MySQL.

Comment: How many pack sizes exist? Is that (the number of possible pack sizes) fixed or it can change?

Comment: There are never more than 4 pack sizes per product

Comment: follow @ypercube's advice, and go here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table. If you post some sample data we can help with implementing and syntax

Comment: And this page has many useful tricks for Pivot tables, from elementary to super-advanced: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1339#78

Comment: Thanks ypercube PIVOT table is the way forward!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  ci.size
  ,sum(if(ci.pack_size=1,ci.price,null)) as pack_size1
  ,sum(if(ci.pack_size=2,ci.price,null)) as pack_size2
  ,sum(if(ci.pack_size=3,ci.price,null)) as pack_size3
  ,sum(if(ci.pack_size=4,ci.price,null)) as pack_size4
FROM catalog_info ci
WHERE ci.product_id = 345
GROUP BY ci.size -- WITH ROLLUP
```

If you uncomment the "WITH ROLLUP" MySQL will add an extra grant total row at the end.

Same query for multiple products.

```
SELECT 
  ci.product_id
  ,ci.size
  ,sum(if(ci.pack_size=1,ci.price,null)) as pack_size1
  ,sum(if(ci.pack_size=2,ci.price,null)) as pack_size2
  ,sum(if(ci.pack_size=3,ci.price,null)) as pack_size3
  ,sum(if(ci.pack_size=4,ci.price,null)) as pack_size4
FROM catalog_info ci
WHERE ci.product_id BETWEEN 1 AND 100
GROUP BY ci.product_id ASC, ci.size DESC -- WITH ROLLUP
```

Note that with rollup you **cannot** add an `order by` clause, but you **can** effect the implicit ordering in the group clause (ASC, DESC) as shown above.
Uncomment the `with rollup` to add a grant total row.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're looking to get a group of all red widgets, including:

- Small red widget
- Small red widget (pack of 5)
- Medium red widget
- Medium red widget (pack of 5)
- Large red widget
- Large red widget (pack of 5)

They all have separate IDs.  If you can guarantee that the IDs will always be in a consecutive range, you could do something like

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id BETWEEN 45 AND 50
```

However, maintaining the consistency of the ID numbers would be a pain in the butt.  The next approach would be to just add a whole bunch of OR clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 
   product_id = 45
   OR product_id = 46
   OR product_id = 47
   OR product_id = 87
   OR product_id = 93
```

But that again wouldn't solve the problem that you don't know the numbers of all the products in a group.

So you're going to need to alter your database in one of two ways.

Method 1: alter the products table to add a new column that contains an ID number for the family of product.  Thus:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN `family_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER product_id
```

Then manually go through and add the same family_id to groups of products:

```
UPDATE products SET family_id = 1 WHERE product_id = 45;
UPDATE products SET family_id = 1 WHERE product_id = 46;
UPDATE products SET family_id = 1 WHERE product_id = 47;
UPDATE products SET family_id = 1 WHERE product_id = 48;
```

So that you can then get them all out with a simple query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE family_id = 1;
```

Method 2: is to create a second table to track relationships between individual products and product families:

```
CREATE TABLE `families` (
`relationship_id` INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`family_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`product_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Then put all your relationship data in there:

```
INSERT INTO families (family_id, product_id) VALUES (1, 45);
INSERT INTO families (family_id, product_id) VALUES (1, 46);
INSERT INTO families (family_id, product_id) VALUES (1, 47);
INSERT INTO families (family_id, product_id) VALUES (1, 87);
```

And you can get it out again with a join:

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p, families f 
   WHERE p.product_id = f.product_id 
   AND family_id = 1;
```

I would tend to prefer the second solution personally, but either way will work.

Comment: He doesn't want to `GROUP BY` nor to get a subset of the products, he needs a pivot table, sometimes called "crosstabs".

Comment: @ypercube: I guess I misunderstood the question. Oh well.